# Contagem Regressiva com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e preciso criar uma pagina com contagem regressiva.

Preciso pegar uma data futura e que faça a contagem regressiva.

Qual a melhor forma?

Comment: E o seu código? Onde você parou? Posta seu código..

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma aplicação parecida em meu projeto para colocar a página em manutenção caso for necessário realizar alguma manutenção.

- Para o código funcionar corretamente é preciso de duas coisas: data inicial e final.

Como pode ver no código abaixo é preciso informar a data como new Date(),
new Date(ANO, MES, DIA, HORA, MIN, SEG), lembrando que o mês começa em 0, Janeiro = 0, Fevereiro = 1, Março =2 , ...

Uma breve explicativa, a cada 0,1s ele da um refresh no código para atualizar o tempo, dentro do código ele inicia uma variável `now`, responsável por controlar o tempo percorrido e a variável `porcentagem` que é responsável por guardar a porcentagem já percorrida.

```js
dateStart = new Date(2019, 5, 29, 12, 00, 00);
dateEnd = new Date(2019, 5, 29, 14, 00, 0);
var start = dateStart.getTime();
var end = dateEnd.getTime();
var dataFinal = verificaZero(dateEnd.getDate()) + "/" + verificaZero(dateEnd.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateEnd.getFullYear();
var horaFinal = " ";
horaFinal += verificaZero(dateEnd.getHours()) + ":" + verificaZero(dateEnd.getMinutes());
var tempoFinal = dataFinal + horaFinal;

function verificaZero(value){
    var result = value < 10 ? "0"+value : value;
    return result;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  var now = +new Date;
  porcentagem = (now - start) / (end - start) * 100;
  if (porcentagem > 100) {
    porcentagem = "100";
  }
  if (porcentagem <= 0) {
    porcentagem = "0";
  }
  if (porcentagem <= 100 || porcentagem > 0) {
    $("#progress-bar").text(parseInt(porcentagem) + "%");
        if (porcentagem < 100)
            $("#porcent").html("Aguarde, data de retorno: " + tempoFinal);
        
        if (porcentagem == 100)
            $("#porcent").html("Aguarde em instantes estaremos online.");
  }
  $('.progress-bar-container').attr('title', parseInt(porcentagem) + "% Completo.");
  porcentagem = porcentagem + "%";

  document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = porcentagem;
}, 100);
```

```css
.manutencao {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.manutencao .logo {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #94D2F8, #3A92C8) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px 0px #222;
}
.manutencao a{color: #77dff1; text-decoration: none;}
@font-face {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.manutencao h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3c8dbc;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.manutencao h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3c8dbc;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.manutencao p {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.manutencao p.credit {font-size: 12px; margin-top: 40px; color: #ccc;}
.manutencao .hr {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.manutencao .clear {
    clear: both;
}
.manutencao .progress {
    height: 70px;
    margin: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #222d32;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
.manutencao .txt-launch-day-hat {
    width: 117px;
    height: 159px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -120px;
    right: -45px;
}
.manutencao .txt-launch-day {
    width: 112px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    right: -40px;
}
.manutencao .progress-bar {
    height: 43px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    position: absolute;
    top:14px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.manutencao .progress-bar-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    
    position: relative;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list h2 {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list form {
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list input[type=text]{
    width:280px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list input[type=submit]{
    width:90px;
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
    text-indent: -5000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list input[type=submit]:hover{
    background-position: 0 -44px;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list input[type=submit]:active{
    background-position: 0 -88px;
}
.manutencao .mailing-list input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#porcent{
    color: #3c8dbc;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="manutencao">
          <section class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar-container" title="99% Completo">
              <article id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></article>
            </div>
          </section>
          <div id="porcent"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```